# Insert partition for preceding period to MS SQL DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, partitioning

I have a partitioned DB on my MS SQL Server 2017. In that DB data stores for two weeks till current date.

An older partition (that is becoming 15th) is deleted at the beginning of new day (with its file and filegroup).
But now I have a terrible situation where I need to create 15th (olderst) partition again.
I've already created filegroup and file for it.

Could you please tell me, how can I include this partition to my Partition Scheme without harming current partitions with it's data?

Supposing if today is 2019-01-24, would it be a right to execute following operations:

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_SCHEMA NEXT USED (PARTITION_2019-01-09)

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_FUNCTION() SPLIT RANGE('2019-01-09')
```

Wouldn't it be harmfull (e.g. data from subsequent partitions would be removed) or incorrect way?

P.S.: there are no any backups for this DB

Comment: It's not harmful in terms of consistency, but splitting non-empty partitions can take a *very* long time and make the table unavailable, because existing data (that's now in the "wrong" partition) has to be moved. Depending on your scenario, getting clever with `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH` can help to empty partitions before the split -- you will then have to get creative about moving the data back, but at least it doesn't lock things like `SPLIT` would.